# Jquery select all checkbox of a div whose id starts with "idName"

Tags: jquery

Following code works fine for single variable idName

```
$('#' +idName+ ' input:checkbox').each(function() {...}
```

where idName is a variable having id of div, for instance abc
But now idName can have any values including abc1, abc2 etc (i.e. abc_).
 I used following code:

```
$('[id^="'+idName+'"] input:checkbox').each(function() {...}
```

But it is not working. Can anybody point it out where I am going wrong?
Sorry for not arranging for a fiddle

Comment: Aside from missing a closing `)` your code should work fine. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: there must be another issue, generally the code should be working, see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jfLeje3k/)

Comment: Ya! I checked console its not giving any error. But the control is not getting  within each, though there are ids with abc1, abc2. ')' is there. So that is not a problem.

Comment: I cleared cache and now its working fine. So no problem in code. Thanks for fiddle @empiric

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
 $("input:checkbox[id="+idName+"]").attr('checked',false);
```

Comment: Buddy id of checkbox is not idName :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/archish1989/azxxa84f/ see these. to check all checkbox of Contact pass 'c' in chkAll() function else 'm'

Comment: @archish where is the reference to the Question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[id*='idName']").each(function(){
    $(this).children('input').attr('checked','checked');
})
```